# Sitecore: How to add a set of "fields" to a rendering

Tags: xslt, sitecore, render

In Sitecore, how would I go about adding a couple of fields to a rendering (.xslt)?

- Changing the "template" of the render, makes it so it is no longer a proper rendering.

The goal is to create a rendering, the user can add to a placeholder in the page editor.

Edit:
Currently im trying the same using sublayouts (.ascx)
- The sublayout is of a template of (..sublayout), with a "custom" template added to the "Parameters Template" field.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show us essential information, such the XML you're working with and the XML output you expect to receive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [Presentation Component XSL Reference](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Presentation%20Component%20XSL%20Reference.aspx) on SDN.

If you are changing the template, you also need to change the rendering control (XSLT or ASCX depending on whether it is a Rendering or a Sublayout) to display the new field you have added to the template.

For example, if you add a field called "summary" of type "Single Line Text" to the template, then you need to add following to the XSLT

```
<sc:text field="summary"/>
```

Section 4.1 has a list of the different field types.

If you are using an ascx control then

```
<sc:FieldRenderer ID="scSummary" FieldName="Summary" runat="server" />
```

Just adding the field to the template will not cause it to appear on the site (unless, of course, you coded your rendering/sublayout to do exactly that).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is currently using fieldrenderer in the Sublayout (.ascx) im getting the fields from the item, instead of from my sublayout (with its __standard values), so fx. using title returns the current items title, and any of the custom fields just returns nothing. Added abit more info.

Comment: That's the expected behaviour, it normally gets the field from `Context.Item` (i.e. the current item). What you would normally do is create a new template with your data types in (which it sounds like you have) and then in the content tree create a new item of that type. Then set layout and add controls you want to item (you should really set on `__standard values` of template...). So item in content tree contains the fields you need for your rendering. Where you have it set now is meant for passing parameters to the control, usually developer controlled variables rather than content.

Comment: Thanks, this cleared some misconception I had regarding presentations and content. I now have a semi working solution, where an item has to be generated for any elements shown. (Though i hate to force the users to come up with a name, when its not really used)

Comment: Yes, you can put them into sections so at least they can be "hidden away" by collapsing the section. You can also create a "standalone" item with your data and no presentation applied to it. When you add the component to your page set the datasource to above item, you need this in ascx controls though: http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/11/How-to-Apply-Data-Sources-to-Sitecore-ASPNET-Presentation-Components.aspx